# Frustrating Formula - Help Needed with Google Sheets formula/method

Tags: math, google-sheets

I am struggling to come up with a formula that fits certain criteria and was hoping someone with a better math brain than me might be able to help. What I have is a Google Sheets based tool that determines how much a someone has purchased of a product and then calculates the amount of times a special additional offer will be redeemed based on the amount spent.

As an example, the offer has three tiers to it. Though the actual costs will be variable for different offers let's say the first tier is gained with a $10 purchase, the second with a $20 purchase and the third with a $35 purchase (the only real relationship between the prices is that they get higher for each tier but there is no specific pattern to the costing of different offers). So if the customer bought $35 worth of goods they would get three free gifts, if they bought $45 worth they would get 4 and then an additional spend of $5 (totaling $50) would then allow them to redeem 5 gifts in total. It can be considered like filling a bucket, each time you hit the red line you get a new gift, when the bucket is full it's emptied and the process begins again.

If each tier of the offer was the same cost (e.g. $5, $10 and $15) this would be a simple case of division by the total purchase amount but as there is no specific relationship between the cost of the tiers (they are based on the value of the contents) I am having trouble coming up with a simple 'bucket filling' formula or calculation method that will work for any price ranges given to it. My current solution involved taking the modulus, subtracting offer amounts from the purchase amount etc. but provides plenty of cases where it breaks . If anyone could give me a start or provide some information that might help in my quest I would be highly appreciative and let me know if my explanation is unclear.! Thanks in advance and all the best

**EDIT:**
The user has three tiers and then the offer wraps around to the start after the initial three are unlocked once, looping until the offer has been maxed out. Avoiding a long sheet with a dynamic column of prices would be preferable and a small, multicell formula would be ideal

[image: This image shows an idea of what I mean, I hope this is now more clear.]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am not quite sure about, everything into one entire formula(is there a formula for loop and building arrays?) 
from my understanding the tier amounts are viable, so every time you add a new tier with a new price limit then it must be calculated with a new limit price number...wouldn't it be much easier to write such module in javascript than in a google sheet? :o

anyways here is my workaround, that may could help you to find an idea

Example Doc
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1z6mwkxqc2NyLJsH16NFWyL01y0jGcKrNNtuYcJS5dNw/edit#gid=0

my approach : 
- enter purchases value
-> filter all items based by smaller than or equal "<=" (save all item somewhere as placeholder)
-> then decrease the purchases value by amount of existing number(max value) based on filtered items
-> save the new purchases value somewhere and begin from filtering again and decreasing the purchases value 
(this needs to be done as many times again, till the purchases is empty)

after that, sums up all placeholder

Comment: Hey! They system you have looks nice, I like the idea of it. I haven't had a chance to play around with it much but from my initial testing it seems like the system breaks down after a user has 3 of each gift, couldn't see why at first glances but as the gifts can be unlocked up to 30 times each in some cases this could be problematic.

Comment: yes you are right, because i added just 3 Filters there...thats why the system breaks when you need more.. in case you need more... you can add more filters.. i put 4 more filters in there for you, but this example was more to show you what kind of stuff is needed :D (i added also a check value, that shows how many filters where needed, for the "input"
(like for 1000€ you need ~ 29 Filters)

Comment: Ahaaaaa, I see now. In which case thanks very much, this could be the thing I needed! My brain was broken so appreciate the assist. Will play around with your solution and mark your answer as correct, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a lookup table. Create a table with the tier value in the left column, and the corresponding number of gifts for that tier value in the right column. Then you can use [Vlookup](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318) to match the amount spent to correct tier.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure this would work so well, I will update my question with a more practical example as it's not as simple as a predefined list of prices that raises for each subsequent gift. In fact I'm specifically trying to avoid a long list like this and hoped to have a formula working across a small amount of cells.

For example, in your above solution you have 4 tiers. In my tool what needs to happen is that after tier 4 is purchased ($45 in your example) the user would wrap back around to tier 1 again, meaning they then have to spend another $10 to get the first gift again.